# Find the number of ways this can be arranged in which no 2 women and no 2 men sit together given 4 men and 3 women are seated in a dinner table?

Tags: permutations

Find the number of ways this can be arranged in which no 2 women and no 2 men sit together given 4 men and 3 women are seated in a dinner table?

@Edit:
They are seating in a row dinner table

I have applied 2 approaches in this question and found both approaches differ according to the Ans
The Ans is 144

> I want to ask why the second approach is wrong?

My 1st Approach:

When i do arrangement like this: first arrange all 3 women  at alternate places i.e  at 2 4 6 or 1,3,5.

Now the next 4  places ca be filled in 4! ways.

So,the required arrangement=4! .3!=144 Ans

2 Approach

When i do arrangement like this: first arrange all 4 men  at alternate places i.e  at 2 4 6 8 or 1 3 5 7.

Now,arrange the 3 Women can be placed at 5 places=5P3=60

The required arrangement=60 . 24=1440

Comment: Are they sitting in a row or in a circle? And if in a circle, are arrangements equivalent if they differ only by a rotation?

Comment: How do you come to $5$ places for the $3$ women in the second approach ?

Comment: @joriki Edited the question

Comment: @Peter 4 men can sit at these places 2 4 6 8 or possible 1 3 5 7.Also,3 women can be placed at any places i.e at 1 3 5 7 9. so i defined 5P3

Comment: @Jalaj Chawla you need to state how many seats are there at this table

Comment: @WojciechKarwacki  7 people 7 seats.And i found my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have place number $8$ as you stated in 2nd approach. Actually this is easy because $7$-seated table forces us to put all men in spots $1,3,5,7$ and all women in spots $2,4,6$, so the question becomes:

In how many ways can I rotate 4 men and 3 women (in groups)?

Is is $4! \cdot 3! = 144$.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 women, the only way one could possibly satisfy the conditions of the question is that the ends are occupied by men.
Supposing you began with a women at the first position you ll get an arrangement like the following
   W M W M W _ _
Given that there are no more women left, the only option is to seat two men in the last two positions, which violates the conditions of the questions